# Ruby convert 2 decimal string into a number and keep the two decimals

Tags: ruby

I want to convert "5565.80" to 5565.80 and "5565.00" to 5565.00. The issue with `to_f` is that it removes the last 0 when the 2 decimals are `.00`. Is there a single way to do both?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. Where did you search, and what did you find and why didn't that help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, where is the minimum code that demonstrates a specific problem you encountered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Float

You can convert "5565.80" to a float :

```
value = "5565.80".to_f
# 5565.8
```

And then display the value with two decimals :

```
'%.2f' % value
# "5565.80"
```

A float has double-precision in Ruby, so your value will actually be :

```
5565.800000000000181898940354...
```

As a float, you cannot save exactly `5565.80`.

## Exact values

### Integer

If you want exact values (e.g. for currency), you could use integers for cents :

```
"5565.80".delete('.').to_i
# 556580
```

When you need the corresponding float, you could divide it by `100.0`.

### Decimal

If you're working with a database, you could use `decimal(20,2)` or something equivalent.

### BigDecimal

You could also use [`BigDecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) :

```
require 'bigdecimal'
BigDecimal.new("5565.80")
```

It will save the exact value but will be much slower than int or float.

Comment: So, the answer is NO :)

Comment: @Ilya The answer is "YES, BUT".

Comment: I think the question is about converting a string to float with double zero in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`#round`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Float.html#method-i-round).

The argument to round is how many decimals you want to round to. Some examples:

```
5565.80.round(2) # => 5565.8 # omits trailing 0's
5565.00.round(2) # => 5565.0 # only keeps the decimal to show that this is a float
5565.79.round(2) # => 5565.79 # rounds to two digits
5565.123.round(3) # => 5565.123 # rounds to three decimal places, so nothing is lost
5565.123.round(2) # => 5565.12 # drops the 3
5565.129.round(2) # => 5565.13 # drops the 9 and rounds up
```